# Definition of Tail-index of a probability distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, distribution-tails

> What is a valid definition of *Tail-index* of a probability distribution?

I understand that it is something to do with the ***rate of convergence*** of the density function $f(x)$ $($to $0)$ as $x \to \infty$. I tried searching *google* and I do find a lot of articles/papers on the topic but nowhere I can find a specific definition of the term.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: There is a defect in the wikipedia page on heavy-tail distributions:  They give three methods of estimating the tail index (starting with Hill's method) without ever defining what the tail index is.

Comment: @MarkFischler Not only just wikipedia, I can't find a proper definition of Tail-index ANYWHERE :-(

Comment: Yes, for example http://users.cms.caltech.edu/~adamw/papers/2013-SIGMETRICS-heavytails.pdf skirts the topic but is careful not to give a useful definition.

Answer (score 7):

I have found a defintion at http://freakonometrics.hypotheses.org/2338, although again it is not presented as a primary definition of "tail index" but rather as an adjunct to the discussion of what they call heavy-tailed distributions.  So I have had to fill in some parts to add a bit of rigor, and other people should check these parts.

The parts obtained from the freakonometrics article are in the shaded areas.

> Consider any distribution $P(X)$ with cumulative distribution function $F(x) = 1- \overline{F}(x)$ defined by $\mbox{Pr }(X > x) =  \overline{F}(x)$, such that
>   for some $\xi>0$,
>   $$
> \overline{F}(x) = x^{-1/\xi}\mathcal{L}(x)
> $$
>   where $\mathcal{L}(x)$ is some slowly varying function for large $x$.
>
> The tail index of the fat-tailed distribution $P(X)$ is by definition $\xi$.

Although the freakomomics article calls this a heavy-tailed distribution, in Wikipedia and elsewhere this is called a fat-tailed distribution.  The definition of a "slowly varying function" is that for all $a>0$
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\mathcal{L}(ax)}{\mathcal{L}(x)}=1
$$
Thus we can restate the condition as $\overline{F}(x)  \sim  x^{-1/\xi}$ for some $\xi>0$, where $\sim$ denotes asymptotic equivalence.

The definition of a heavy-tailed distribution given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy-tailed_distribution is that  $P(X)$ is a heavy-tailed distribution if for all $\lambda > 0$, 
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{\lambda x}\overline{F}(x) = \infty
$$
All fat-tailed distributions are heavy-tailed in this sense, but not vice-versa.

---

**Added example in response to comments**

For example, consider the probability distribution function $$f(x)=\left\{\matrix{0&x<1\\\frac{e^{1-\sqrt{x}}}{2\sqrt{x}}&x\geq 1}\right.
\\\overline{F}(x)= e^{1-\sqrt{x}}\mbox{ for } x\geq 1
$$ For any positive $\lambda$ 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{\lambda x}\overline{F}(x) = \infty$$ so the distribution is heavy-tailed. But for any positive $\xi$, 
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{1/\xi}\overline{F}(x) = 0 
$$
which implies that the distribution is not fat-tailed

---

> Equivalently, there exists a slowly varying function $\mathcal{L}^*(x)$ such that for $0<p<1$, $$ \log F^{-1}(1-p) = - \xi \log p + \log\mathcal{L}^*(1/p)$$
>
> $\xi$ can by visualized as the opposite [negative] of the slope, at small $p$, of $\log F^{-1}(1-p)$ when that is plotted against $p$.

Somebody should add this definition to the Wikipedia page on heavy-tailed distributions, just above the section on Pickand's estimator of the tail index. However, I think the Freakonometrics reference is inadequate, both because it is not primarily intended as a definition of the term, and because the confusion about heavy-tailed and fat-tailed reduces confidence in using that as a reference.

Comment: Can you give an example of heavy-tailed distribution which is not fat-tailed distribution, please.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response (+1). And yes, I'm wondering what could be a tail-index for distributions that are heavy-tailed but are not fat-tailed.

Comment: Consider the probability distribution function given in the newly added part of the answer.  The distribution falls off more slowly than exponentially, but more rapidly than any negative power of $x$.

Comment: "we can restate the condition as $\overline{F}(x)  \sim  x^{-1/\xi}$ for some $\xi>0$, where $\sim$ denotes asymptotic equivalence" Actually we cannot, at least not if "asymptotic equivalence" has its usual meaning.

Answer (score 0):

For an academic reference, a definition is given in the paper ["The impact of competition on prices with numerous firms"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022053116300035) by Xavier Gabaix, David Laibson, Deyuan Li, Hongyi Li, Sidney Resnick and Casper G. de Vries (Journal of Economic Theory, 2016) -- see Definition 1. For any distribution with cdf $F$ and pdf $f$, and support $(w_{l}, w_{u})$, the tail index $\gamma$ is defined

$$ \gamma := \lim_{x \to w_{u}}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1-F(x)}{f(x)}\right).$$

They provide a number of examples in their Table 1.